# Adding a byte to the first byte of an uint32

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm playing little bit with bitwise operators in c.

I have the following:

```
uint32 myValue = 0x00ffffff;
```

I want to add a byte with the value 0x33 to the first byte of myValue to have at the end this:

```
myValue = 0x33ffffff;
```

I'm trying to do it with:

```
myValue = ((myValue & 0xff) << 0) | (0x33u & 0xff);
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You want `(0x33u << 24) | myValue`. Or if you want to make sure the MSB is zero: `(0x33u << 24) | (myValue & (0xFFu << 24))`

Comment: when you say "add", what do you mean? The example is unclear as `myValue` starts with `0x00` and you use `|` in example.

Comment: `first byte` has no meaning without giving also a ordering. Are you talking about the most significant byte or the least significant byte?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the unclear description I meant the MSB.

Comment: Your example is for MSB

Comment: Correction again (typing to fast). Yes I meant MSB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
int main() {
    uint32_t myValue = 0x00ffffff;
    myValue = myValue | (0x33u << 24);
    printf("%x\n", myValue); //====> 0x33ffffff
}
```

Comment: you should use `uint32` instead. `unsigned int` isn't always 32 bit